# ErrorException : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in View - Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-8

I try to make a simple form.
When i want to make form for edit the data, it always pop up error like that.

This is my edit form

```
@section('title', 'Form Edit Mata Kuliah')

@section('header')
<h1 class="page-header"><b>Form Mata Kuliah</b></h1>
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'updatekuliah')) }}
@endsection

@section('navigation')
<p>Edit Data Kuliah</p>
@endsection

@section('content')
@foreach($datakuliah as $p)
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ Form::label('kodematakuliah', 'Kode Mata Kuliah') }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md">
        {{ Form::label('',':') }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        {{ Form::text('kodematakuliah', $p->kodematakuliah_db, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Masukkan Kode Mata Kuliah')) }}
    </div>
</div>
<br>
{{ Form::submit('Kirim', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
@endforeach
@endsection
```

This is my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Pertemuan6Controller extends Controller
{
    public function tampilkanformedit($kodeedit)
    {
        $varkuliah = DB::table('tabel_pertemuan6')->where('kodematakuliah_db', $kodeedit)->get();
        return view("pertemuan6.formedit", ['datakuliah' => $varkuliah]);
    }
}
?>
```

This is my route

```
Route::get('/formkuliah', [Pertemuan6Controller::class, 'tampilkanformtambah']);
Route::get('/editkuliah/{kodeedit}', [Pertemuan6Controller::class, 'tampilkanformedit']);

Route::post('/insertkuliah', [Pertemuan6Controller::class, 'insertdatakuliah']);
Route::post('/updatekuliah', [Pertemuan6Controller::class, 'updatedatakuliah']);
Route::get('/deletemhs/{nimhapus}', [Pertemuan6Controller::class, 'deletedatamahasiswa']);
```

Anyone know how to handle that error? Thanks before

Comment: Include more details from the error message.

Comment: ErrorException
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\projectlaravel\resources\views\pertemuan6\formedit.blade.php)
http://localhost:8000/editkuliah/halo

Comment: What is `DB::table(...)->get()` returning - check the returned value?

Comment: Yes, they check the data that i want to edit based on kodematakuliahdb

Comment: Your comment does not answer my question. What data is returned and its type? Edit your question with those details.

Comment: Returned an array

Comment: If is an array you can't do this $p->kodematakuliah_db, instead of that check for the pair key-value and must be something like $p['kodematakuliah_db']

Answer (score 0):

You can pass only array and collections to foreach loop. Actually get method should return empty array if it doesn't have any value. If I'm not wrong, your query passes NULL. That's why you are getting this result. Check the value before passing it to the view.

Answer (score 0):

This should return **`collection`** and not null:

```
`$results = DB::table('tabel_pertemuan6')->where('kodematakuliah_db',` `$kodeedit)->get();`
```

**Do**

```
var_dump($results);
```

**or**

```
dd($results);
```

and check if you get expected values. Expected is collection. Check here for more info [here](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_get)